# How to retrieve a selected row's form MySQL database and send back the information to Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am working on an Android project and I am completely new to Android. I'm following the below tutorial [link](http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/). My project is about police registry system. I am connecting to MySQL database with the help of PHP and JSON.

I have created a form where user's can register and they can login using their user name and password. Also I have made a form where user can register their complaint and complaints are stored in a single database known as `db_complaints` in the database. I am able to retrieve all complaints using following PHP code.

```html
<?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.inc.php");

//initial query

if (!empty($_POST)) {
 //initial query
 $query = "INSERT INTO complaints ( username, title, message ) VALUES ( :user, :title, :message ) ";

    //Update query
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':title' => $_POST['title'],
  ':message' => $_POST['message']
    );


  
//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();
    
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();
        $post["post_id"]  = $row["post_id"];

        $post["username"] = $row["username"];
        $post["title"]    = $row["title"];
        $post["message"]  = $row["message"];
        
        
        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }
    
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    
    
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}}

?>
```

i want to retrieve a particular user complaints separately so they can view there complaints in my_complaints form but i am not able to do this and i have been stuck.

Comment: That code is to save a complaint. Have you written any code to read a complaint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty neat using prepared statements and error handling, so where is your problem actually?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE username = :user";
$query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username']);
```

That query should do the trick to retrieve complaints from a specific user.

Comment: i used the code but php script is saying "no postavailable" :(

Comment: thank you so much i used your php code in my php form and altered my android code a bit and its totaly working fine now i am able to retirive a perticular user's complaint easily when they login thank you :)

Comment: Ok, nice! Could you upvote the answer and accept it? :D

Answer (score 1):

and this is the code i am using in android to retrieve all the user complaint's

```html
package com.example.policadda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Mycomplaints extends ListActivity {

 // Progress Dialog
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 
 //php read comments script
    
    //localhost :  
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
   // private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/comments.php";
    
    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://www.iamnotcrazy.hol.es/webservice/mycomplaints.php";
    
  //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://www.mybringback.com/webservice/comments.php";
   
  //JSON IDS:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_COMPLAINT_ID = "complaint_id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
    //it's important to note that the message is both in the parent branch of 
    //our JSON tree that displays a "Post Available" or a "No Post Available" message,
    //and there is also a message for each individual post, listed under the "posts"
    //category, that displays what the user typed as their message.
    

   //An array of all of our comments
    private JSONArray mComments = null;
    //manages all of our comments in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.my_complaints);   
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onResume();
     //loading the comments via AsyncTask
     new LoadComments().execute();
    }

 public void addComment(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Mycomplaints.this, Complaints.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves json data of comments
     */
 public void updateJSONdata() {

        // Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
     // we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
     // to the json element name, and the content, for example,
     // message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..
     
        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        
        // Bro, it's time to power up the J parser 
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
        //back a JSON object.  Boo-yeah Jerome.
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

        //when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
        //try to catch any exceptions:
        try {
            
         //I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail." (success==1)
         //before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
         //mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
         //available
            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                //gets the content of each tag
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String content = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
              
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, content);
                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
             
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);
                
                //annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array list
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into our listview
     */
 private void updateList() {
  // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
  //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
  //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
  //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
  //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
  //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
    R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_SUBJECT,
      TAG_USERNAME }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
      R.id.username });

  // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  
  // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
  //could do something.  However, we will choose
  //to do nothing...
  ListView lv = getListView(); 
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {

    // This method is triggered if an item is click within our
    // list. For our example we won't be using this, but
    // it is useful to know in real life applications.

   }
  });
 }       

    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

     @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Mycomplaints.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Loading complaints...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
   pDialog.show();
  }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         //we will develop this method in version 2
           updateJSONdata();

            return null;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
          //we will develop this method in version 2
            updateList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i altered as your suggestion in php

```html
<?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.inc.php");
//initial query
$query = "Select * FROM complaint WHERE username= :user";
$query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username']);
//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();
    
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();
        $post["complaint_id"]  = $row["complaint_id"];
        $post["username"] = $row["username"];
        $post["title"]    = $row["title"];
        $post["subject"]  = $row["subject"];
        
        
        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }
    
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    
    
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

and i altered my android in such a way that where i used shared preference to store the username and send it to php and php can receive the username and execute the code :) . below is my android code.

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Mycomplaints extends ListActivity {

 // Progress Dialog
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 //php read comments script
    
    //localhost :  
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
   // private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/comments.php";
    
    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String READ_COMPLAINTS_URL = "http://www.iamnotcrazy.hol.es/webservice/mycomplaints.php";
    
  //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://www.mybringback.com/webservice/comments.php";
   
  //JSON IDS:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_COMPLAINT_ID = "complaint_id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
    //it's important to note that the message is both in the parent branch of 
    //our JSON tree that displays a "Post Available" or a "No Post Available" message,
    //and there is also a message for each individual post, listed under the "posts"
    //category, that displays what the user typed as their message.
    

   //An array of all of our comments
    private JSONArray mComments = null;
    //manages all of our comments in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.my_complaints);   
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onResume();
     //loading the comments via AsyncTask
     new LoadComments().execute();
    }

 public void addComment(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Mycomplaints.this, Complaints.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves json data of comments
     */
 public void updateJSONdata() {

        // Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
     // we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
     // to the json element name, and the content, for example,
     // message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..
     
        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        
        // Bro, it's time to power up the J parser 
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
        //back a JSON object.  Boo-yeah Jerome.
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMPLAINTS_URL);
        
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Mycomplaints.this);
            String post_username = sp.getString("username", "diva");
        //when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
        //try to catch any exceptions:
        try {
              List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
               Log.d("request!", "starting");

        JSONObject json1 = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
          READ_COMPLAINTS_URL, "POST", params);
         //I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail." (success==1)
         //before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
         //mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
         //available
            mComments = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                //gets the content of each tag
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String content = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
              
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, content);
                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
             
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);
                
                //annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array list
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into our listview
     */
 private void updateList() {
  // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
  //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
  //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
  //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
  //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
  //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
    R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_SUBJECT,
      TAG_USERNAME }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
      R.id.username });

  // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  
  // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
  //could do something.  However, we will choose
  //to do nothing...
  ListView lv = getListView(); 
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {

    // This method is triggered if an item is click within our
    // list. For our example we won't be using this, but
    // it is useful to know in real life applications.

   }
  });
 }       

    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

     @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Mycomplaints.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Loading complaints...");
   pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   pDialog.setCancelable(true);
   pDialog.show();
  }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         //we will develop this method in version 2
           updateJSONdata();

            return null;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
          //we will develop this method in version 2
            updateList();
        }
    }
}
```